# 1 email with many BCC or many emails with 1 recipient each?

Tags: postfix, email-server, mailing-list

**Contexte**: wordpress mailing list, private hosted postfix server, ~1K recipients.

**Question**: Should I

1. send one mail for each recipient **or**
2. a single mail with all recipients in BCC **?**

What is good practice ? Does this have any effect on reputation/spam score ?

---

**More context:**

I am currently using a wordpress plugin that send everything in a single mail with the hundreds of recipients in BCC. 
I would like to change that in order to be able to add nice stuff `List-Unsubscribe` header and link, that sort of things I can only do with one email per recipient.

But if I do that, wouldn't I run into some problems sending so many mails at once ? Must I consider use of some queuing software in addition to postfix built-in mechanism ?

*Note: I already read the tuning postfix documentation of postfix, so I am aware of the kind of things I **can** do (like having a local DNS, etc..). But I don't know what I should expect / **should** do.*

Comment: I should add that I noted (in postfix logs) that currently, many recipient servers (especially MS and Yahoo ones) have huge delays, sometimes (often?) because of "too many recipients".

Comment: [Edit your question](https://serverfault.com/posts/893773/edit) rather than to clarify it with comments, please. - All things considered  generating and sending 1000 unique  messages isn’t a that big of a deal and you get the benefits you already explained